# Removing the component Id from validation message when using message bundle in JSF

Tags: jsf

I am practising JSF. I created a login screen with user Id and password fields. Now both the input fields have required="true". I created message.properties file and added the below validation Id to it,

> **javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED= {0} is mandatory field**

I added message-bundle to the faces-config.xml.

No when I click the submit without any field value given, the message shown is as below,

> **j_idt13:userid is mandatory field**

I want to remove that **j_idt13** which is the component Id from the message.
How to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the input components, use the attribute `label` to show that instead of the id:

```
<h:inputText .. label="User Id" />
```

Comment: It works great. Actually I tried label="" thinking {0} is auto replaced by the given component id value. :-) ....

Comment: Glad to help! Sorry, I should learn how to express it better.